# Pinning cloth to animated model is making cloth go crazy

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

Something is wrong with my cloth. 
I made a wizard robe skirt but it goes out of shape when I bake it.

Here is my [file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/d3opr9z8pjzpjkf/Help.blend).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few things that seem to be causing this.

The main thing was that the legs had a largish *outer* collision margin which was causing the robe to collide constantly.

Try changing this to something like .004 on both legs:

[image]

Also try making the skirt bigger initially. There has to be room for the legs to move ;)

Result:

[image]

I also pinned the entire top edge loop instead of just the corner vertices, reduced the collision quality to about 3 and disabled self collision. These massively decreased the bake time without a lot of visual impact once the collision issue was fixed.